# How to share a Word 2016 .docx with external file references (fields) with other users without errors

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word 2016.

Imagine 4 documents: A, X, Y, and Z.

A is a "master" document that includes the text of X, Y, and Z utilizing the "INCLUDETEXT" field.  I use it to make customized versions of A.

X, Y, and Z occasionally change and sometimes I don't need to include them all in the document I'm producing, using A, for a particular client.

If I update A and customize it for a particular client (we'll call the new document A-sub), it will appear on my computer and properly contain all the text of X, Y, or Z, whichever I choose to include.  If I send A-sub to the client, it won't be functional because their file location will not be the same as mine and the fields will return errors.

Is there any way to "flatten" (I don't know the right word) a document so that I can email A-sub to someone else without there being an error?  I want whatever text was displayed in the INCLUDETEXT field to be "frozen" in place as part of a functioning Word .docx

I suppose I could use relative file locations rather than absolute file locations, but I want to avoid sending a whole directory in a .zip file each time.

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting the content by using an `INCLUDETEXT` field, on the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Object** > **Text from File**. In the dialog box, select the file to insert, specify specific bookmarked sections of that file by clicking **Ranges** (if appropriate), and then click **Insert**.

(If you were to do the same thing but click the drop-down arrow in the **Insert** button and then click **Insert as Link**, you'd end up with an `INCLUDETEXT` field; so the two procedures are equivalent, except that one inserts static text, whereas the other inserts linked, updatable text.)

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to keep them linked until I choose to share it?  I want to have a Master File and what I provide would be a snapshot of that document at any given time, but editable like a normal Word Doc.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll need to use the Master Document functionality (View tab > Outline > Show Document). After you've inserted subdocuments into your master, you can click Show Document, place the cursor in the text of a subdocument, and click Unlink. Until that time, any changes that you make in the master will be propagated to the subdocuments, and vice versa.

Comment: I've never used this feature, so will have to experiment a bit.  Thank you!